# Definition of normed and inner product space

Tags: definition, normed-spaces, inner-products

I was reading some Wikipedia pages about [Normed Vector spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normed_vector_space) and [Inner product spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space#Definition) and, in the definitions, they always talk about vector spaces over either $\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb C$.

Is this because most of the useful normed and inner product spaces are over $\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb C$ or is those spaces only defined for vector spaces over those specific fields?

Edit: After debating this topic in the comments of this post I want to rephrase my question:

> Let $V$ be a vector space over a field $\mathbb F$. What condition should $\Bbb F$ verify if we want $V$ to be able to be an inner product space? How about a normed vector space?

Comment: note that finite fields are not ordered

Comment: Yes, but there are more infinite fields than just $\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb C$ @J.W.Tanner

Comment: And why can't we have a norm in a field that is not orderd? @J.W.Tanner

Comment: the norm must be non-negative

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't a norm a real-valued function, so if $\Bbb F$ is a finite field then we can define: $|| \cdot ||: \Bbb F \to \Bbb R^{+}$ right? @J.W.Tanner

Comment: that Wikipedia page says an inner product maps two vectors to an element of the field

Comment: Oh, you're right. So that means that we can't have an inner product space of a finite field. How about an infinite field that is not $\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb C$? @J.W.Tanner

Comment: Your question ask been asked here before; e.g., [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2823699/why-does-the-inner-product-require-the-base-field-be-mathbbr-or-mathbbc)

Comment: Check edit @J.W.Tanner

Comment: Reading linear algebra done right would help.

Comment: You need to consider a lot of things to generalize inner products in a useful way. They should probably still be bilinear (or something generalizing the idea of sesquilinear) forms into a valued field (a valuation is something similar to an absolute value, but with images in an arbitrary ordered field). If we want to define a norm from the inner product, we need to be able to take square roots of positive numbers and have them be positive, so the valuation should take values in a real closed field.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it works over any normed field (at least the normed space, for inner product spaces I'm not sure, since you'd need some generalisation for complex conjugation). A normed field $k$ is a field equipped with a norm $||\cdot||: k\to \mathbb{R}_{\ge0}$ such that

- $||x||=0\Leftrightarrow x=0$
- $||a+b|| \le ||a|| + ||b||$
- $||a\cdot b|| = ||a||\cdot||b||$

If your field $k$ has a discrete valuation $\nu$ that you can build a norm by defining $||x||:=\exp(-a\nu(x))$ for any positive $a$...

In any case, I am sure that Bourbaki will provide you with the most general definition.

And if you want to relax the condition that the norm map to $\mathbb{R}_{\ge0}$, I think there is also a way to do that, and just have it map to some kind of totally ordered semiring...